# Dynamically change a tag content on click

Tags: jquery, angularjs

[image]

I am trying to change value of subtotal field dynamically using angular js. I am stucked at a point. When I click on a `Remove` it removes the particular field using jquery.

On removing the a particular item the `subtotal` value should also change. How to achieve this?

Here is code which I tried.

**Html file-**

```
<div  data-ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CalController" id="parentContainer">

<div class="itemsQuantity" data-id="">
<span>Remove &nbsp;</span>
Qty: <input  ng-model="firstItem" type="text" ng-change="calculateFirst()"/>
<div id="productOne"> Rs {{firstCalculation}} </div>
</div>

<div class="itemsQuantity" data-id="">
<span>Remove &nbsp;</span>
Qty: <input ng-model="secondItem" type="text" ng-change="calculateSecond()" />
<div id="productTwo"> Rs {{secondCalculation}} </div>
</div>

<div class="itemsQuantity" data-id="">
<span>Remove &nbsp;</span>
Qty: <input ng-model="thirdItem" type="text" ng-change="calculateThird()"/>
<div id="productThree"> Rs {{thirdCalculation}} </div>
</div>

<!-- Subtotal -->
<div>
Subtotal: 
<p id="finalPrice">Rs {{firstCalculation + secondCalculation + thirdCalculation}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**Js File**

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/41hjl",function(response){
    var availableSections = $j(".itemsQuantity");

    for(i=0; i<response.product_id_count.length; i++){
        $j(availableSections[i]).attr("data-id",response.product_id_count[i]);
    }
});
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('CalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstCalculation = 200;
  $scope.secondCalculation = 400;
  $scope.thirdCalculation = 600;

      $scope.calculateFirst = function() {
        $scope.firstCalculation = $scope.firstItem*200;
    };

      $scope.calculateSecond = function() {
        $scope.secondCalculation = $scope.secondItem*400;
    };

      $scope.calculateThird = function() {
        $scope.thirdCalculation = $scope.thirdItem*600;
    };

    $j(".itemsQuantity span").on('click',function(){
        var removeProduct = $j(this).parent().attr("data-id");
        $j(this).parent().remove();
    });

}])
```

Comment: First, mixing jQuery with Angular is bad practice.  Second, where is your function for finalCalc() on your ng-click?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Check the edited post.

Comment: are you using data-id ? if you are then use that value to know which item you are removing (first/ second/ third) then make value 0

Comment: and as @RaniRadcliff mention, dont mix jquery and angular.. instead use only angular

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Angular [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I4aecizKfpb5iOn2G9iN?p=preview) example using a filter without the use of jQuery.

Your HTML:

```
   <table style="width:100%">
  <tr ng-repeat="i in cartItems">
    <td>{{i.name}}</td>
    <td><button type="button" ng-click="removeItem(i)">Remove</button></td>
    <td>{{i.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{i.price}}</td>
    <td>{{i.price * i.quantity}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td>{{cartItems | totalSumPriceQty: 'quantity':'price'}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Your js:

```
 $scope.removeItem = function(item){
      var idx = $scope.cartItems.indexOf(item);
      $scope.cartItems.splice(idx, 1);

    }

});

app.filter('totalSumPriceQty', function () {
    return function (data, key1, key2) {        
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key1)  && angular.isUndefined(key2)) 
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach(data,function(value){
            sum = sum + (parseInt(value[key1]) * parseInt(value[key2]));
        });
        return sum;
    }
})
```